# PHP: No space between html tags when rendered from single <?php?>

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, echo

this is a curious question, and I would like to know why it happens..

I am using `Yii2` framework and I created a `widget` to render a thumbnail from `Twitter bootstrap`, I have made the code to render multiple buttons if it was needed, but when I render more than 1 buttons, they seem to not be any space between each other, I checked the `HTML` code and it seems to be fine, I even compared the view with 2 same codes, one from `PHP` and another from just `HTML`,

this is how it looks, both have same HTML code, but the first one is rendered from PHP
[image]

this is how the `HTML` code is, both cases have the same code, the difference is that the first one comes from `php`

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>testing</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="/localhost/backend/web/site/index">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="/localhost/backend/web/site/index">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="/localhost/backend/web/site/index">Button</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>testing</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="/localhost/backend/web/site/index">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="/localhost/backend/web/site/index">Button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="/localhost/backend/web/site/index">Button</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code from both cases. They are not the same, or they'd be rendering the same!

Comment: @miken32 the code was added

Comment: This is not possible. The browser only receives the html, but never knows what happens at server side. Proably, when you use php, it trims the surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by adding `regex` between each element

for example we have multiple elements being processed in a `foreach` loop in `php` and the result is concatenated in a string

```
<?php 

function createButtons($data)
{
    /**
     * [$html Here is where the html buttons are going to be stored]
     * @var string
     */
    $html = '';

    /**
     * This will generate Html Button for each element in the array and concatenate into $html as string like this:
     * <button><button><button><button>
     */
    foreach($data as $button)
        $html .= Html::Button($data['name'], $data['options']);

    return $html;
}
```

in order to make make it create a new line for each element, a `"\n"` which is a `regex` code to add a new line

```
<?php 

function createButtons($data)
{
    /**
     * [$html Here is where the html buttons are going to be stored]
     * @var string
     */
    $html = '';

    /**
     * This will generate Html Button for each element in the array and concatenate into $html as string like this:
     * <button>
     * <button>
     */
    foreach($data as $button)
        $html .= Html::Button($data['name'], $data['options'])."\n"; //This "\n" adds a new line in the string

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I would say this isn't the best solution. Your design (css), shouldn't be forced white-space characters in your html. It should be handler by css only, so it won't be so brittle, and changes could be done without breaking the visual. Html 'whitespace' can be modified/removed on the way from server to client, and this could also break things.

Answer (score 1):

Php cancels out white spaces by default. You can however tell it to add white spaces by using &nbsp.

This is the syntax:
echo str_repeat(' ',1);

The first argument will add whitespace, the second argument is how much space you want to add

You can put it after echoing your button

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try to insert html comments between the buttons because spaces have width also.
E.g.

```
<input .... /><!--
--><input .... /><!--
--><input .... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% sure this would be because of combination of css and the outputed html.

If you have for the button element css style: `display: inline-block` and there is at least one space  between the html tags you'll get the spaces (new lines also count)
with: space

```
 <button>foo</button>
 <button>bar</button>
```

without space

```
 <button>foo</button><button>bar</button>
```

the reason why with php its withou spaces is probably because during the rendering there is stripping of white space occuring

Also if the posted code is from `inspecting the code` with chrome or whatever, its not the real code structure its formated. try looking at right-click -> source code

#### if you want to fix it.

it could be solved by:

- changing your css for the element to `display: block; float: left` -> making it block element with flaots.
- changing your css to for using `display: flex` - google this if you don't know it.
- removing spaces between html tags / minify html - and keep `display: inline-block`

Comment: i am using `element inspector` from `mozilla firefox`, like you said, the code from the inspector looks good structure, but i followed your suggestion checking the source code and i saw that the first come is all place in a single line

Comment: @nosthertus so that just confirms what I said, there is minifier for the html before serving it to server, to save data transfer. That also answers why it happens. updated answer why how to fix also

Comment: i suppose i should just add new lines between buttons in the code, that's all i want

Comment: @nosthertus ahh you want to have the spaces :) ... yes add new lines, or disables minifier for that part template, or use `display: block` with float and add margins .. or flex with margins.

Comment: i fixed it, i will add an answer to show how i did it